# Squarespace: disable parallax scroll on mobile only

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, squarespace

Example template: https://eamon-demo.squarespace.com/#overview-eamon

Parallax scrolling tends to stutter on mobile phones, so I'd like to disable it once the screen size is a certain width. I have had luck so far changing the fonts for smaller screens with this in the Custom CSS section:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   h1 { font-size: 60px; }
   h2 { font-size: 35px; }
   h3 { font-size: 30px; }
   body { font-size: 18px; }
 }
```

Squarespace provides a button in the Design tab you can tick to turn parallax on and off. Is there a way to have that button ticked through custom CSS when the screen size gets smaller? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If SquareSpace prevents you from disabling the parallax effect, you can try overriding the `transform` property manually:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #parallax-images .image-container img {
        transform: initial !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful in that it can turn off parallax effect on certain pages. Now all I need to figure out is the code that will get the width of the page, and apply your code only if the width is < 640.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable parallax on mobile view through squarespace using the below custom css to target and override the figure element's style:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
  figure[style] { 
    transform: initial !important; 
  } 
}
```

It will apply to screens with width less than or equal to 640px and override the [transform css property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp), which is what essentially dictates the parallax.